# Transcend 1TB could not complete chkdsk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk, bad-sectors, exfat

I have 1TB Transcend External HDD around 2 years old. In the HDD, there are 3 Partition:-

i) Local Disk (J:) [~90GB] - exFAT

ii) Local Disk (E:) [~400GB] - NTFS

iii) Local Disk (H:) [~488GB] - NTFS

I have a number of .RW2 files transferred from a friend past few months into J: and never opened the folder after few weeks later. Not long after the transfer, I found out that every time I connect my HDD to my PC, it lags my PC to the point that it crashes the Windows Explorer. Ever since, I rarely plugged it in and now I can't convert the .RW2 files to .JPG  as the converter said "Could Not Read File". So I tried to do a chkdsk, and this happened.

[image: After]
*After "The volume will be checked for bad sectors.", chkdsk took 15 minutes before exiting and did nothing to the disk.*

A friend suggested me to use PartitionGuru. Without the HDD attached, the program opens smoothly. But once I plug in the HDD, the program stop responding. I tried leaving the program to respond for almost a day, but to no avail. I guess I should mention that when I want to open the Disk Management, it takes almost 30 minutes to show all the drives details.

I'm not sure what to do as those .RW2 files are needed and my friend who transferred it to me had lost those exact files on his computer.

P/S: There is no clicking sound or any abnormal sounds. Everything works like normal except that it loads slowly on Windows 7, 8, and 10 laptop, and it won't load at all in Windows XP Desktop PC as I've tried to plug it in using SATA cables too. The HDD utilizes a dual USB to a Mini USB.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: STATUS UPDATE.. I installed the HD Tune and started the program. Its working fine without the external HDD plugged in, but as soon as I plugged it in, TOTAL LAG. I can't open the program at all. I waited for a whole day but nothing happens. I will try to let it go for another few days.

Comment: @DavidPostill Status Update 2 - Up until now, I cannot open programs that utilizes the HDD to load. It's been 3 days, and not even a single HDD repair program or even the Windows Explorer is functioning well. I mean I can utilize Windows Explorer but after sometime, if I rush the Explorer, it becomes unresponsive and crashes unless I force unplug the external HDD. When I force unplug, all the HDD repair softwares will magically appear and work. I did remember a few weeks back having one of my external HDD's partition deleted and the HDD works better after the partition delete. Kindly advise.

Comment: Sounds like your disk is dead. Take it to a recovery specialist if you are desperate for the files.

Comment: Thank for your time. At least I know this kind of problems points to dead disk. I update any info when I send the disk for recovery.

Comment: I managed to delete the other partitions and was able to access the programs. here is the [status of the HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZLd.png)

Comment: Yes. It is dying and could fail at any time.